# Crosshair highlight for table on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the code below that works perfect for crosshair function. This is fine, however wondering if there is a way to stop the highlight beyond the cursor (hover).

For example, instead of a "cross" shape highlight you end up with a backward "L" shape highlight. So instead of highlighting the whole row & column it only highlights column 3 down to row 2 and row 2 only to column 3. No extended highlight.  Hope that makes sense?

Here is my css code:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
.permissions table,
th,
td {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size:13px;
}

td, th, .row, .col, .ff-fix {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

tr, col {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td:hover {
    background-color:red;
}

td:hover:first-child {
    background-color:red;
}

td:hover:nth-child(3n) {
    background-color:red;
}

tr:last-child td:hover {
    background-color:red;
}

td:hover::before,
.row:hover::before,
.ff-fix:hover::before { 
    background-color: #ffa;
    content: '\00a0';  
    height: 100%;
    left: -5000px;
    position: absolute;  
    top: 0;
    width: 10000px;   
    z-index: -1;   
}

td:hover::after,
.col:hover::after,
.ff-fix:hover::after { 
    background-color: #ffa;
    content: '\00a0';  
    height: 10000px;    
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;  
    top: -5000px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;        
}
```

Here is my html code:

```
<table>
    <col /><col /><col />
    <tr>
        <th class="col">First Name</th>
        <th class="col">Middle Name</th>
        <th class="col">Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Jeffery</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lois</td>
        <td>Marie</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Margie</td>
        <td>Ann</td>
        <td>Thatcher</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am having some trouble understanding the desired behavior.  Perhaps try to rephrase?  Also, a JSFiddle would help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following the logic of your CSS, you apply a full-width `::before` and a full-height `::after` which are displayed over the table. To adjust how these are displayed (a cross vs a "backward L"), adjust the corresponding horizontal and vertical positioning.

Try replacing your `td:hover::before` and `td:hover::after` selectors with the following to display the highlighting as a "backward L". Note the positioning is set using `right` and `bottom` rule sets, as opposed to your original positioning using `left` and `top`.

```
td:hover::before,
.row:hover::before,
.ff-fix:hover::before { 
  background-color: #ffa;
  content: '\00a0';  
  height: 100%;
  right: 90px;
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0;
  width: 10000px;   
  z-index: -1;   
}
td:hover::after,
.col:hover::after,
.ff-fix:hover::after { 
  background-color: #ffa;
  content: '\00a0';  
  height: 10000px;    
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;  
  bottom: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;        
}
```

See how it looks in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ocuvhx8e/).

Comment: I'm sorry about my down vote.
It looks like I've made it by mistake.
Also, it will be nice if the program does not color the header row. Just my point of view. :-)
All the best, @agrm!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but [here's a method using Javascript](https://codepen.io/luttenegger/pen/vYgWmxz). I prefer this method because it allows for custom backgrounds, and doesn't require CSS workarounds.

HTML:

```
<table id="hoverTable">
  <thead>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th>Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    <th>Column4</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Item</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

SCSS:

```
body {
  background:grey;
}
.hoverHighlight {
  background-color:yellow !important;
  cursor:default;
}

#hoverTable {
  font-family:arial;
  border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  th, td {
    border:2px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
  }
  th {
    background:#1167b1;
    color:white;
  }
  td {
    text-align:center;
    background:#d0efff;
  }
}
```

Javascript:

```
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    addHoverEventsAndClasses();
  })

  function toggleHighlight(element, trueOrFalse) {
    const currentRow = returnCurRow(element);
    const index = element.currentTarget.cellIndex;
    const table = document.getElementById('hoverTable').rows;
    for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        const data = table[i];
        const cells = data.querySelectorAll(".cell");
        if(data.rowIndex === currentRow) {
            cells.forEach((td) => {
                trueOrFalse ? td.classList.add("hoverHighlight") : td.classList.remove("hoverHighlight");
            });
        }
        cells.forEach((cell) => {
            if(cell.cellIndex === index) {
                trueOrFalse ? cell.classList.add("hoverHighlight") : cell.classList.remove("hoverHighlight");
            }
        });
    }
};

function addHoverEventsAndClasses() {
    const mainTableTDs = document.querySelectorAll("#hoverTable td");
    const mainTableTRs = document.querySelectorAll("#hoverTable tr");
    //Dynamically add class names to each row and cell to target
    addClass(mainTableTDs, "cell");
    addClass(mainTableTRs, "row");
    mainTableTDs.forEach((td) => {
        td.addEventListener("mouseenter", highlightCol); 
        td.addEventListener("mouseleave", removeHighlightCol);
    });
}
//Helper function for adding highlight classes
function addClass(el, cl) {
    el.forEach((child) => {
        child.classList.add(cl);
    });
};
//Toggle highlight functions. Did it this way so multiple arguments could be passed
function highlightCol(e) {
    toggleHighlight(e, true);
}
function removeHighlightCol(e) {
    toggleHighlight(e, false);
}
//Grab the current row
const returnCurRow = (e) => {
    return e.currentTarget.parentElement.rowIndex;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Shepherd. It works nice!
However, I found a small issuse with the styling classes.
The row "addClass(mainTableTRs, "row");" should be "addClass(mainTableTRs, "cell");".
Otherwise all the cells were by one cell per row. Which is a kind of list, not table. :-)
Regards.